# setTimeout и while

Tags: javascript

Здрвствуйте, имеется вот такой код.

```
let a = 0;

function message(val, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(val);
    }, 1000);
    callback();
}

while (a < 5) {
    message(a, () => {
        a++;
    });
}
```

Хотел реализовать так, чтобы каждую секунду выводилось сообщение в консоли, которое передаётся в функцию, а увеличение счётчика происходит в обратном вызове функции. Однако фунция setTimeout асихнронна, поэтому не ожиадает своего выполнения. Поэтому возникает вопрос, как реализовать вывод счётчика в консоль с интервалом в 1 секунду? Для этого необходимо, чтобы увеличивался тайм-аут для каждого следюущего шага? Если так, то есть ли ещё какие-либо способы выполнения подобной задачи. И почему при увеличении счётчика тайм-аута внутри его функции, происходит зацикливание. Например, для такой программы:

```
let b = 0;
while (b < 5) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(b);
        b++;
    }, 1000); 
}
```

Comment: В последнем случае цикл никогда не передаст управление, потому что условие прекращения цикла находится в асинхронном вызове setTimeout, который записывается в конец очереди, которая не заканчивается)) А так можно использовать генератор или асинхронный итератор или setInterval или многими другими способами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть замечательная функция `setInterval();`

```
var repeat = 5; //количество повторений
var b = 0; // ?ваше значение?

var intervalId = null; // переменная для хранения идентификатора таймера

intervalId = setInterval(()=>{
 console.log(b++);
 if(repeat <= 0){ // количество повторений закончилось
  clearInterval(intervalId); // прекращаем данный цикл (таймер)
 }
 --repeat; // каждый вызов мы уменьшаем количество повторений
}, 1000);
```